# How to negate a predicate in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a predicate function that accepts a string and evaluates it to `bool`:

```
def pred(line):
    return someval in line
```

Now I have a strings list and want to select only those which don't match the predicate. I'd expect code like below:

```
my_list = ["Thanks","in","advance!"]
not_pred = negate(pred)
new_list = filter(not_pred, my_list)
```

I suppose Python has something similar to a `negate` function but I could not find any. What is a convenient Python way for this?

I know it can be achieved with lambda but I feel there's an easier standard way.

Comment: `itertools.filterfalse` perhaps?

Comment: not <some expression>  negates it. not True == Fasle ... and not False == True

Comment: Python isn't too keen on FP-style higher-order functions. I can't imagine the few it has being accepted if they were proposed today (though the new `operator.call` is basically just the old `apply` function from Python 2).

Comment: If you had something like `toolz.functoolz.compose`, you could write`filter(compose(operator.not_, pred), ...)`.

Comment: [operator.not_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__not__)

Answer (score -1):

To negate something use "not":

- not  negates it.
- not True == Fasle
- and not False == True

Without changing too much of your code you can negate the predicate this way:

```
someval = 'an'

def pred(line):
    return someval in line 

my_list  = ["Thanks","in","advance!"]
new_list = filter(lambda x: not pred(x), my_list)

print(list(new_list))
```

result is:

```
['in']
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is what the OP was alluding to when they said "I know it can be achieved with lambda "

Comment: @chepner maybee but he did not showed his code so ... this may help if he needed help. lambda is quite common in Python and quite easy to use, so he will choose the answer which help him.

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't be too difficult to write your own `neg_unary_pred` function.

```
>>> def neg_unary_pred(f):
...   def f2(x):
...     return not f(x)
...   return f2
... 
>>> def even(n): return n % 2 == 0
...
>>> list(filter(neg_unary_pred(even), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
[1, 3, 5]
```